# Buttons 'flickering' in angular application using ng-if or ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've had this same issue in two different angular applications I've worked on and yet I have been unable to find any discussion of this problem - which makes me think perhaps I am missing something. Let's say I have a view of a 'task' which can be in a number of different states including 'pending', 'accepted' and 'completed'. Different action buttons will be shown depending on the state of the task, for example:

```
<button ng-if="task.status === 'pending'" ng-click="ctrl.acceptTask()">Accept</button>

<button ng-if="task.status !== 'accepted'" ng-click="ctrl.acceptTask()">Flag</button>
<button ng-if="task.status === 'accepted'" ng-click="ctrl.flagTask()">Complete</button>
```

The issue is that when the user clicks the accept button, for a brief period both of the buttons below will be displayed. It's as if angular is sequentially working through the DOM and for the brief period between ng-ifs, both the 'flag' and 'complete' button are displayed because only one has been updated. This occurs for ng-show as well.

Note, this is not an issue that can be solved with ng-cloak, which is only there to prevent a template being displayed before angular has done its magic.

Given I've encountered this issue on both of the two large angular applications I've worked on, it must be a common problem. Any suggestions as to how this is typically solved? (PS, the above HTML is just an example of what I mean, it's not my actual template.)

Answer (score 5):

That is because ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM. When an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. also,ngIf recreates elements using their compiled state.

Indeed having ngIf evaluate to false will remove the element. But only if it is not set to true immediately after, as angular only refresh the DOM (your HTML) when it has the opportunity to do so, i.e. after the current synchronous block of code.

Below code snippet does not have any effect:

```
$scope.task.status= 'pending'; <br/>
$scope.task.status= 'accept';
```

This will

```
$scope.task.status= 'pending';
// $timeout will wait for a digest cycle before executing the code
// Angular will remove the button from the DOM
$timeout(function() {
   $scope.task.status= 'accept';
   // Here a second digest cycle happen, angular will put the button back into the DOM
});
```

Please note that it might be due to your angular app emerges many watchers due to heavy DOM contents. I have made one [simple](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/N2qIMRyDj2SX2BdBleU4/) plunker to replicate your scenario but not facing it. You can check and reduce watchers by adding available chrome plugin and/or many others way like [this](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef). Just google it and you can find a treasure of lots of fruitful information to improve watcher count of your app.

Ok now I got it what exactly you do require here:) See !! [This](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) is what angular docs told us "Note especially the powerful **ng-switch** that should be used instead of several mutually exclusive ng-shows." One of the [good](http://codereply.com/answer/64jdb8/conditionally-apply-css-styles-angularjs.html) read on "When to use what!!!". So i hope flickering buttons will not happen if you use the ng-switch at those instances or alternatively we can achieve the scaffold of solution that is quite generic and works without worrying about current scope at all by using directive initialization function to inter-instances communication. See [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/v7LNRzF7I83yU2XMqJJr/preview) in which i have applied class to multiple buttons in mutually exclusive way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do understand the digest cycle. What I'm trying to determine is how to ensure that only one element is displayed at a time when you have two mutually exclusive ng-ifs.

Comment: @seesharper I have edited my answer based on your comments.I hope it will resolve things for you now. Also if possible could you please build a small plunker or jsfiddle to replicate your flickering button paradigm so it would be an added advantage to resolve things quickly.

Comment: @seesharper Could you please try with [ng-cloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) on your buttons to prevent the html template from being briefly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The below ng-if statements ensures that it will display one at a time. If you see it both at the same time it should be because something in your code is messing with angular digest cycle which delaying the two way binding of the fields and rendering of the buttons.

```
<button ng-if="task.status !== 'accepted'" ng-click="ctrl.acceptTask()">Flag</button>
<button ng-if="task.status === 'accepted'" ng-click="ctrl.flagTask()">Complete</button>
```

Comment: Downvoted because I explicitly stated that the above code showed the flickering problem, and there is no solution offered.